# Ranking de conteo de registros continuos por campo auto incrementable

Tags: mysql

!Que tal!
Tengo una tabla como muestra la primer imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi idea es crear un contador llamado calcula que se reinicie cada vez que el **idjor** no es continuo ya que este es un campo auto incremental como por ejemplo en el caso que pasa del

- 7 al 12 que son 7 registros continuos
- 12 al 22 que son 11 registros continuos
- 27 al 29 que son 3 registros continuos

Este es el código que pretendo utilizar donde si el idjor es igual al siguiente idjor me sume uno al contador en caso que no sea así el contador se reinicia

```
SET @var1=1;
SELECT fcdb_alineaciones.nombre, fcdb_jugadoras.nombre, @var2:=fcdb_jornadas.id as idjor, fcdb_jornadas.jornada,
CASE
    WHEN @var1 = @var2 THEN @var1=1
    WHEN (@var1+1) = @var2 THEN (@var1+1)
    ELSE @var1:=1
END AS calcula
FROM fcdb_alineaciones
INNER JOIN fcdb_jugadoras ON fcdb_alineaciones.nombre = fcdb_jugadoras.id
INNER JOIN fcdb_jornadas ON fcdb_alineaciones.jornada = fcdb_jornadas.id
ORDER BY fcdb_alineaciones.nombre, fcdb_jornadas.id
```

El resultado que busco es como la segunda imagen que muestre por orden descendente el ranking denso, el paso importante es el **calcula** que cuenta los registros continuos por el **idjor**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Con una combinación de funciones de ventana (MySQL 8) y variables de usuario:

```
SELECT j.nombre
     , count(1) calcula
     , dense_rank() OVER(order by count(1) desc) ranking
  FROM ( SELECT nombre
              , jornada
              , @j := @j + cambio grupo
           FROM ( SELECT nombre
                       , jornada
                       , jornada 
                        -ifnull( lag(jornada) OVER ( partition by nombre 
                                                     order by jornada
                                                   )
                               , 0            
                               ) > 1 cambio
                    FROM fcdb_alineaciones
                ) discontinuidades
             JOIN (SELECT @j:=0) v
        ) g
     INNER JOIN fcdb_jugadoras j
       ON j.id = g.nombre
  GROUP BY j.nombre, g.grupo
  ORDER BY calcula DESC
```

Son tres consultas anidadas:

- Consulta más interna (discontinuidades).
  Con ayuda de la función de ventana `lag()` verificamos si hay discontinuidad respecto a la jornada anterior.
- Consulta intermedia (g).
  Simplemente crea un número de grupo de jornadas `@j` con base en las discontinuidades; si hubo discontinuidad incrementa el número de grupo.
- Consulta externa.
  Agrupando por jugadora se cuenta el número de jornadas según el grupo y se aplica ese mismo conteo a la función de ventana `dense_rank()` para determinar el ranking.

Comment: Gracias por responder tan rápido, funciona bien en mi host de prueba local pero en mi host remoto no, estuve investigando al parecer la versión antigua del host remoto no soporta las funciones de ventana